# Gnu Radio Compile on Ubuntu Unit Test qa_ofdm_txrx failes

Tags: linux, gnuradio

I built  GNU Radio and followed this Guide: https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/UbuntuInstall#Installing-GNU-Radio.

Make runs fine.

But when I start

```
make test
```

qa_ofdm_txrx failes.

Whenn i run

```
ctest -V -R ofdm_tx
```

there is a unresolved Name:

```
packet_nu_tag_key
```

Can some one tell me which library is missing?

I didn't get any matches by Google when i search for `packet_nu_tag_key`.

Edit:

What i forgot to mention is it is Ubuntu 14.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`packet_nu_tag_key` is actually a typo (hence a bug). I'll have a pull request up in a minute; I'd expect this to be solved rather quickly.

However, if it's only that unit test that fails for this reason, congratulations, you have a successfully built GNU Radio. Continuing to (`sudo`) `make install` will set it up correctly.

If you want to try my bugfix:

```
git pull https://github.com/marcusmueller/gnuradio.git digital_fix_typo_nu_num
```

in your `gnuradio` repository.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this in the evening.

Comment: By the way was the typo in the test source or in gnu radio?

Comment: @maxbit89: in the test; but we all consider the tests to be integral part of GNU Radio -- without them, we wouldn't be anywhere close to what GNU Radio is now.